# Understanding why $(e_{1}-e_{2}) \otimes (e_{1}+2e_{2})= e_{1} \otimes e_{1} +2e_{1} \otimes e_{2} -e_{2} \otimes e_{1}-2e_{2} \otimes e_{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Im trying to properly understand tensor products, for this Im following these notes:

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Here the author as a first example in the page 1 considers $\mathbb{R}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{2}$ he  explains an element $v \otimes w \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{2}$ can be regarded as a linear combination of elements $e_{i} \otimes e_{j}$ where $e_{i}$ is an element of the canonical basis $\lbrace  e_{1}, e_{2}\rbrace$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Therefore he claims $\mathbb{R}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{2}$ has basis $\lbrace e_{1} \otimes e_{1}, e_{1} \otimes e_{2}, e_{2} \otimes e_{1}, e_{2} \otimes e_{2} \rbrace$. In this fashion in equation (1.1) he considers an element $v \otimes w$ where $v= e_{1} - e_{2}$ and $w=e_{1} +2e_{2}$.  So

$$ v \otimes w= (e_{1}-e_{2}) \otimes (e_{1}+2e_{2})$$. But I dont understand why

$$(e_{1}-e_{2}) \otimes (e_{1}+2e_{2})= e_{1} \otimes e_{1} +2e_{1} \otimes e_{2} -e_{2} \otimes e_{1}-2e_{2} \otimes e_{2}?$$

I undestand the overall idea is to express $ v \otimes w= (e_{1}-e_{2}) \otimes (e_{1}+2e_{2})$ as a linear combination of $\lbrace e_{1} \otimes e_{1}, e_{1} \otimes e_{2}, e_{2} \otimes e_{1}, e_{2} \otimes e_{2} \rbrace$ and we also have some sort of distribution among tensor product and sum but after about an hour or two I still cannot figure out this process?

Comment: he is motivating what tensor product should look like and work. He literally says mentions it in the first paragraph and says the rigorous definitions are to follow in Section $3.$

Comment: Just before the example, he wrote „ then expanding out $v \otimes w$ as if $\otimes$ were a noncommutative product (allowing scalars to be pulled out)“. You will eventually learn that the tensor product is bilinear and this is what was used here.